# loop through json elements for a list of values

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
import json, re, sys
x = json.loads('''{"status":{"code":"200","msg":"ok","stackTrace":null},"dbTimeCost":11,"totalTimeCost":12,"hasmore":false,"count":5,"result":[{"_type":"Compute","_oid":"555e262fe4b059c7fbd6af72","label":"lvs3b01c-ea7c.stratus.lvs.ebay.com"},{"_type":"Compute","_oid":"555e27d8e4b059c7fbd6bab9","label":"lvs3b01c-9073.stratus.lvs.ebay.com"},{"_type":"Compute","_oid":"555e27c9e4b059c7fbd6ba7e","label":"lvs3b01c-b14b.stratus.lvs.ebay.com"},{"_type":"Compute","_oid":"555e2798e4b0800601a83b0f","label":"lvs3b01c-6ae2.stratus.lvs.ebay.com"},{"_type":"Compute","_oid":"555e2693e4b087582f108200","label":"lvs3b01c-a228.stratus.lvs.ebay.com"}]}''')
print x['result'][4]['label']
sys.exit()
```

The desired result should be all the labels.  But, when I run it, it only prints the first label. What am I doing wrong here?

And also, before I could figure out that "result" was the key to use, I needed to copy and paste the json data to a site like "jsonlint.com" to reformat it in a readable fashion.  Im wondering if there's a better way to do that, preferably without having to copy and paste the json data anywhere.

So two questions:

1. How do I get the above code to list all the labels
2. How do I know the key to the field I want, without having to reformat the given ugly one liner json data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a list comprehension to get all label

**Ex:**

```
import json, re, sys
x = json.loads('''{"status":{"code":"200","msg":"ok","stackTrace":null},"dbTimeCost":11,"totalTimeCost":12,"hasmore":false,"count":5,"result":[{"_type":"Compute","_oid":"555e262fe4b059c7fbd6af72","label":"lvs3b01c-ea7c.stratus.lvs.ebay.com"},{"_type":"Compute","_oid":"555e27d8e4b059c7fbd6bab9","label":"lvs3b01c-9073.stratus.lvs.ebay.com"},{"_type":"Compute","_oid":"555e27c9e4b059c7fbd6ba7e","label":"lvs3b01c-b14b.stratus.lvs.ebay.com"},{"_type":"Compute","_oid":"555e2798e4b0800601a83b0f","label":"lvs3b01c-6ae2.stratus.lvs.ebay.com"},{"_type":"Compute","_oid":"555e2693e4b087582f108200","label":"lvs3b01c-a228.stratus.lvs.ebay.com"}]}''')
print [i["label"] for i in x['result']]
sys.exit()
```

**Output:**

```
[u'lvs3b01c-ea7c.stratus.lvs.ebay.com', u'lvs3b01c-9073.stratus.lvs.ebay.com', u'lvs3b01c-b14b.stratus.lvs.ebay.com', u'lvs3b01c-6ae2.stratus.lvs.ebay.com', u'lvs3b01c-a228.stratus.lvs.ebay.com']
```

You can use `pprint` to view your JSON in a better format.

**Ex:**

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(x)
```

**Output:**

```
{u'count': 5,
 u'dbTimeCost': 11,
 u'hasmore': False,
 u'result': [{u'_oid': u'555e262fe4b059c7fbd6af72',
              u'_type': u'Compute',
              u'label': u'lvs3b01c-ea7c.stratus.lvs.ebay.com'},
             {u'_oid': u'555e27d8e4b059c7fbd6bab9',
              u'_type': u'Compute',
              u'label': u'lvs3b01c-9073.stratus.lvs.ebay.com'},
             {u'_oid': u'555e27c9e4b059c7fbd6ba7e',
              u'_type': u'Compute',
              u'label': u'lvs3b01c-b14b.stratus.lvs.ebay.com'},
             {u'_oid': u'555e2798e4b0800601a83b0f',
              u'_type': u'Compute',
              u'label': u'lvs3b01c-6ae2.stratus.lvs.ebay.com'},
             {u'_oid': u'555e2693e4b087582f108200',
              u'_type': u'Compute',
              u'label': u'lvs3b01c-a228.stratus.lvs.ebay.com'}],
 u'status': {u'code': u'200', u'msg': u'ok', u'stackTrace': None},
 u'totalTimeCost': 12}
```

Answer (score 2):

just change your code which is used to print the label

```
print x['result'][4]['label'] # here you are just printing the 4th label only
```

to

```
 print [i["label"] for i in x['result']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop all the result. You result is a list of object which has the label.

```
labels = [ i.get('label') for i in x.get('result')]
print(labels)
```

Use `.get()` it will not return None if the key is not available.